# How to intercept Jackson JsonNodes deserialization

Tags: java, jackson

In my programm I'm doing:

```
private static final ObjectMapper MAPPER = new GridJettyObjectMapper();
....
JsonNode node = MAPPER.readTree(content);
```

My JSON contains a lot of SAME strings and I would like intercept readTree() method and put into TextNodes cached Strings (using WeakHashMap for example).

I hope this will save me a lot of memory. For now my app just OOME and in heap dump I see millions of same Strings in TextNodes.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: You can use `-XX:+UseStringDeduplication` as a JVM flag for new versions of Java 8 and above. This will save on memory by having the JVM keep the Strings in memory only once.

Comment: Thanks, Adam. But I'm on Java 7 and can not use this option.

Answer (score 0):

After some debug I replaced

```
JsonNode node = MAPPER.readTree(content);
```

with

```
Pojo p = MAPPER.readValue(Pojo.class, new PojoDeserializer());
```

And implement in PojoDeserializer logic that do not generate many TextNodes.
I used JsonParser streaming API.